# Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

I just installed `Xcode 8 beta 2` and `iOS 10 beta`. I have an existing project where I updated from swift 2.3 to swift 3 based on a prompt from Xcode. I received an error with my code data code.

This was auto generated in the conversion from swift 2.3 to swift 3 by xcode

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<AnyObject>!
```

the error I'm receiving is

```
 Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'
```

I tried to conform AnyObject

```
extension AnyObject: NSFetchRequestResult {}
```

But I receive another error

[image]

I am not sure what I need to do or if my fetchedResultsController needs to be changed in the first place.

ANSWER: `var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Content>!`

Comment: What else as `NSManagedObject` (or a subclass) do you want to use in `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: @vadian class Content: NSManagedObject. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Actually it's a rhetorical question: `NSFetchedResultsController` works only with `NSManagedObject` which conforms to `NSFetchRequestResult`. Extending `NSFetchRequestResult` to `AnyObject` is useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Xcode converter likely was confused about what `Entity` you wanted to return in this fetched results controller. Replace `AnyObject` with the entity type you are fetching.

You should open a radar (bugreporter.apple.com) on this, since it should never suggest `AnyObject` here. At worst it should suggest `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: I was able to remove the error with the code: var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Content>!